# A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, database, web-config

I am facing a very weird problem with my server and website.

My sites were working fine last week. but suddenly they stop working.

the ISSUE is with the database connection. the credentials I provided there is for my new server. but website checking the database on the old server which now close.

I have checked my code many times there is no reference to the old server IP address.

I publish my whole code again and delete the site HTTPDOCS folder's file and uploaded the new files still no Luck.

Please help in this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: DId you check the `web.config`?

Comment: Yes I have check the config file. the connection string is fine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem which I was having is the connection to the database and I was not sure why this was happening. Because my database was working fine.

after hours of search, I found that the problem was not in my code or database. it was acutely an API which stopped working without any notice and causing me this problem.

So in future, you face a problem like make sure all your API's are working fine without wasting time on something else.

Thanks for your help.